# Só aparece zeros na divisão

Tags: c, tipagem, float, divisão

O resultado da divisão é só zero, o que tem de errado?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{   
    double Nota1, Nota2, MediaPond;
    printf("Escreva a nota 1: ");
    scanf("%f", &Nota1);
    printf("\nEscreva a nota 2: ");
    scanf( "%f", &Nota2 );
    MediaPond = ((Nota1 * 2) + (Nota2 * 3)) / 5;
    printf("\nA media ponderada e: ");
    printf("%.2f", &MediaPond);
    system("pause");
}
```

Esse é o retorno do programa

> Escreva a nota 1: 2
>
> Escreva a nota 2: 5
>
> A media ponderada e: 0.00

Comment: Você sabe que só pode aceitar uma resposta? Pode votar em todas que quiser no site todo, mas aceitação só em uma resposta da sua pergunta. Não tem problema aceitar qualquer uma que achar a mais correta, mas muitos usuários acabam trocando a aceitação achando que pode aceitar mais que um, então quando aceita uma nova e deixa de aceitar a outra. Se fez porque queria não tem problema, se o fez por engano seria bom rever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro principal está na leitura das variáveis declaradas como `double`. Quando se usou a função `scanf`você armazenou essas variáveis utilizando o `%f`,o correto nesse caso seria usando `%lf`. Exemplo :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

double n1,n2;

printf("Nota 1: ");
scanf("%lf",&n1);

printf("Nota 2: ");
scanf("%lf",&n2);

printf("Media : %.2lf\n",(n1 + n2) / 2);

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Tem outros erros, mas não o que está descrevendo. Precisa mandar imprimir com o formato de `lf` para `double` e não faz sentido mandar imprimir o endereço de uma variável com `&`, nem precisa criar essa variável, usando os padrões normais de como se costuma codificar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {   
    double nota1, nota2;
    printf("Escreva a nota 1: ");
    scanf("%lf", &nota1);
    printf("\nEscreva a nota 2: ");
    scanf("%lf", &nota2);
    printf("\nA media ponderada e: ");
    printf("%.2lf", (nota1 * 2 + nota2 * 3) / 5);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yjgoqg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FormatDoublec). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/FormatDouble.c).